# How to import a.csv file into a postgresql database using \copy?

Tags: postgresql, windows, pgadmin, psql, csv

I am trying to import a .csv file into a postgresql database. I am using pgadmin III for that on a win7 machine.

My query looks like that:

```
\COPY pop_grid(GRID_ID, POP_TOT, YEAR, METHD_CL, CNTR_CODE, DATA_SRC) from 'C:\...\popgrid.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV;
```

The data inside the .csv looks like that:

```
1kmN5142E2862   2   2006    D   IS  AIT
1kmN5141E2862   13  2006    D   IS  AIT
```

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE pop_grid 
(
    GRID_ID      text            PRIMARY KEY,
    POP_TOT      int         NOT NULL,
    YEAR         date        NOT NULL,
    METHD_CL     varchar(2)      NOT NULL,
    CNTR_CODE    varchar(32)     NOT NULL,
    DATA_SRC     varchar(4)      NOT NULL
);
```

Why do I get this error?

```
ERROR: Missing data for column "pop_tot"
CONTEXT: COPY pop_grid, Row 1: "1kmN5142E2862;2;2006;D;IS;AIT"
```

There is nothing missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You tell the `COPY` command to look for commas as delimiters (`DELIMITERS ','`), but there are no commas in your CSV.  Use the 'text' format instead (it's the default, so you don't have to specify it) and do not specify a delimiter:

> The default is a tab character in text format.

([source](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html))

Comment: yeah, that was it! I should really at least try to understand what I'm copying :) The delimiters was actually ';' instead of ','. They were missing in my question, because I copied it out of excel.